# Mule Code to convert CSV without headers into CVS with headers

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I want to convert a CVS which I'm reading from Object Store and while retrieving the value from that Object I'm getting below output,
INPUT to Object store:

```
   %dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "licNo" : attributes.queryParams.LicNo,
    "errMsg" : attributes.queryParams.errMsg
}
```

Output I'm getting after using RetrieveAll node is below:
Output:

```
    12344,12345,12346
Server Error,Mule Error,Server Error
```

But the output I want is given below:

```
Licence No.,Error Message
12345,Mule Error
10234, Error
12045,Server Error
12305,Mule Error
```

I have deployment in few days, please someone help me.
TIA

Thanks and Regards,
Kunal Awasthi,

Comment: It is not clear how you got that output from the object store. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Provide as text XML the flows to reproduce the issue and the actual values of `attributes.queryParams.LicNo` and  `attributes.queryParams.errMsg`. If you are doing any transformations add them.